# For binded listview how to bind icon of row for selectefd row

Tags: listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I have binded list with iteam,and i want to bind icon of success for selected item.How to do that,to i set for selected item in list view see icon of success for that row.
[image]

My xaml code:

```
ViewCell
    ViewCell.View
        Grid
            Grid.RowDefinitions  
                RowDefinition Height="*"Â
                RowDefinition Height="1"Â
            Grid.RowDefinitions  
           Grid
                Grid.ColumnDefinitions
                    ColumnDefinition Width="*"Â
                    ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"Â
                Grid.ColumnDefinitions
                Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Text="{Binding NazivRegije}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Teal" FontSize="Medium"
            Grid
            StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="Gray" HeightRequest="1"

            Image Grid.Column="1" x:Name="selectionImage" IsVisible="True" Source="SelectedGreen.png" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center"
        Grid
    ViewCell.View
/ViewCell
```

Comment: How do you know the selected item is "successful"? Is there a property on the model? Or some combination of properties?

Comment: You could check my answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you had used MVVM , you just need to bind the property **IsVisible** of image to a property of your model .

### in xaml

```
<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectItems}">
```

```
<Image Grid.Column="1" x:Name="selectionImage" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" Source="SelectedGreen.png" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```

### in code behind

The icon will visible when you click  the item .

#### in model

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string NazivRegije { get; set; }

    private bool isVisible;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        set
        {
            if (isVisible != value)
            {
                isVisible = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
            }
        }
        get { return isVisible; }
    }

    public MyModel()
    {
        IsVisible = false; // set it as false in default
    }
}
```

#### in viewmodel

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyItemsSource { get; set; }
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    MyModel selectItem;
    public MyModel SelectItems
    {
        get
        {
            return selectItem;
        }

        set
        {
            if (selectItem != value)
            {
                selectItem = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsVisible");

                //check or uncheck the item here

                SelectItems.IsVisible = !SelectItems.IsVisible;

            }
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>() {

              new MyModel(){NazivRegije="11111" },
              new MyModel(){NazivRegije="11111" },
              new MyModel(){NazivRegije="11111" },
              new MyModel(){NazivRegije="11111" },
              new MyModel(){NazivRegije="11111" },
              new MyModel(){NazivRegije="11111" },
              new MyModel(){NazivRegije="11111" },
              new MyModel(){NazivRegije="11111" },
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you its work.Can you tell me how to set all images from list to set to false.I want on button X clear all success clicked item.And one more question,how to set specific item from list to be visible icon when initalize view model,i hint database sql to see for user what is his settings and for that need me...

Comment: You could binding a command to Viewmodel . And set all IsVisable  in MyitemsSource as false (in a foreach).

Answer (score 2):

To achieve your requirement use ListView’s TapCommand to update the value of IsSelected property . Bind IsSelected property and a converter to the Source of Image element like in the following code snippet,

**Code Snippet XAML :  Binding Property and converter to Image Source**

```
<ContentPage.Resources> 
    <ResourceDictionary> 
        <local:Converter x:Key="converter"/> 
    </ResourceDictionary> 
</ContentPage.Resources> 

<syncfusion:SfListView ItemsSource="{Binding bookList}"  
                           x:Name="listView" 
                           ItemSize="60" SelectionMode="Single" 
                           SelectionBackgroundColor="AliceBlue" 
                           AllowKeyboardNavigation="True" 
                           TapCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}"> 
        <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate> 
            <DataTemplate> 
                <Grid> 
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" /> 
                        <RowDefinition Height="1" /> 
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                    <Grid> 
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> 
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" /> 
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  
                               LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Author}"  
                               VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start"  
                               FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Teal" FontSize="Medium" /> 
                    </Grid> 
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="Gray"  
                                 HeightRequest="1"/> 

                    <Image Grid.Column="1" x:Name="selectionImage"  
                           HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" 
                           Source="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"  
                           HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center"/> 
                </Grid> 
            </DataTemplate> 
        </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate> 
    </syncfusion:SfListView>
```

**Code Snippet C# : Converter Class**

```
class Converter : IValueConverter 
{ 
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    { 
        return (bool)value ? "Checked.png" : "Unchecked.png"; 
    } 

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    { 
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    } 
}
```

**Code Snippet C# : TapCommand execute method**

```
private Command<object> _itemTappedCommand; 

public Command<object> ItemTappedCommand { get => _itemTappedCommand; 
set => _itemTappedCommand = value; } 

public ViewModel() 
    { 
        ItemTappedCommand = new Command<object>(ItemTappedExecute); 
    } 

private void ItemTappedExecute(object obj) 
    { 
        bool IsSelected = ((obj as Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ItemTappedEventArgs).ItemData as BookInfo).IsSelected; 

        foreach (var item in bookList) 
        { 
            item.IsSelected = false; 
        } 
        if (IsSelected) 
        { 
            ((obj as Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ItemTappedEventArgs).ItemData as BookInfo).IsSelected = false; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            ((obj as Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ItemTappedEventArgs).ItemData as BookInfo).IsSelected = true; 
        } 
    }
```